# .net6 - AWS Lambda function - can't read App.config

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

With this C# - AWS Lambda function code I'm preparing the configuration builder and the service collection.
**Note that I'm using AWS Systems Manager Nuget package.

While I'm able to access

```
configuration["connectionstring-ec2"]
```

I'm not able to access values in a App.config file

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["swApiEndpoint"]
```

Am I missing something?

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddSystemsManager(path: $"/lp-erp/");

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            serviceCollection
                .AddLogging()
                .AddTransient<IParentPublisher, ParentPublisher>()
                .AddDbContext<LPContext>(
                    options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration["connectionstring-ec2"]),
                    ServiceLifetime.Transient
                 )
                
            .AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleNotificationService>();
```

Comment: Are you migrating from .NET Framework to .NET 6? `app.config` is a legacy concept from .NET Framework, so I wouldn't expect it to work out-of-the-box in .NET 6.

Comment: No I created the project in .NET6 directly. Do you suggest using another settings file?

Comment: Tried with appsettings.json as well, same result, config values are not accessible. Seems like SystemManager config is overriding all the rest.



<code>var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddSystemsManager(path: $"/lp-erp/")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);</code>